# Select data from table if not empty, else select whole table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

So, i have this table

```
*COURSE_NO|COURSE_NAME*
CS 155   |  Programming in C++
MIS 101  |  Intro. to Info. Systems
MIS 301  |  Systems Analysis
MIS 441  |  Database Management
MIS 451  |  Web-Based Systems
```

What i need to do is:
show courses with the word 'java' in their name, and if there is no data just show the whole table.
i am stuck with this one for hours, would appreciate any help.

Comment: Do consult your course material, teaching assistant or teacher. Meanwhile checkout http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic on how to ask questions.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I just read it, I'll try to post much clearer questions from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *have* do this in one query, something like this would work:

```
select t1.* from my_table as t1
where t1.COURSE_NAME like '%java%'
or not exists
   (select t2.* from my_table as t2
    where t2.COURSE_NAME like '%java%');
```

But why not just make your life simpler and break this up into 2 operations each with its own query? First issue this simple query:

```
select * from my_table
where COURSE_NAME like '%java%';
```

If you get some rows back, display them (or whatever your application does). If you get no rows back, simply run this query next:

```
select * from my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select COURSE_NO, COURSE_NAME
FROM (SELECT *, 
             COUNT(CASE WHEN COURSE_NAME LIKE '%java%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
                  OVER () jc
      FROM YourTable) ILV
WHERE jc=0 OR COURSE_NAME LIKE '%java%'
```